# Add items to array (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist, addition, extend

I got some `newCity`:

```
ObservCity newCity = new ObservCity ()
{
 id = localCityId,
 entries =  somecity.ToArray()
};
```

Now I load saved city:

```
ObservCity loadOldCity = await myService.loadCity(id);
```

How to **add** `newCity.entries`  to `loadOldCity.entries`?

This don't work

```
newCity.entries.Concat(loadOldCity.entries);

//save newCity + loadOldCity 
myService.saveCity(newCity);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not posted any class declarations, so I will take a guess and say `entries` is either an `IEnumerable` or an array, based on your current code. I will also assume the whole property is read-only. So you just create a new instance:

```
var updatedCity = new ObservCity
{
 id = localCityId,
 entries = newCity.entries.Concat(loadOldCity.entries).ToArray()
};

myService.saveCity(updatedCity);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a range of items with the `AddRange()` method.

```
newCity.entries.AddRange(loadOldCity?.entries);
```

Comment: `.AddRange()` is **not** a method from `System.Linq`, but a method from the `List<>` class.

Comment: @nvoigt You are correct. Should have checked before answering.